# ElasticSearch - Using "now" range in query_string returns 0 hits

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, query-string, elastic-stack, elk

When I try to run query "myfield < now" inside Kibana DevTools Console it returns zero hits. However when I run same query inside Kibana Discover it returns many hits.

How to get same hits inside console using "now" range?

This is how my request inside console looks like:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "myfield < now"
    }
  }
}
```

P.S. myfield is Date field

P.P.S. I am using 7.5.0 version of Elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `query_string` (which uses the [Lucene expression language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges)) you need to do it this way:

```
GET /myindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "myfield:[* TO now]"
    }
  }
}
```

In recent versions of Kibana, the search bar uses [KQL, the Kibana Query Language](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kuery-query.html) which supports the `<` operator.